# How can I have make build intermediate C++ files in a scratch directory with the IDL compiler?

Tags: c++, gnu-make, automake, corba

I have a build process that invokes the CORBA IDL compiler to generate .cc files as an intermediate step, and I'd like for these files to be created in a scratch directory to make cleanup easier with make clean.

I have the following automake rule that works:

```
if MAKE_CORBA
IDLFLAGS = -bcxx

$(shell mkdir -p ${srcdir}/idlscratch/

%SK.cc: %.idl
    $(IDLCC) $(IDLFLAGS) @^

EXTRA_CORBA_SOURCES = ${srcdir}/blahSK.cc

endif
```

This rule works, but it places the .cc files in *${srcdir}* instead of *${srcdir}/idlscratch/* so I changed it to the following rule that does not work:

```
if MAKE_CORBA
IDLFLAGS = -bcxx -C${srcdir}/idlscratch/

$(shell mkdir -p ${srcdir}/idlscratch/

%SK.cc: %.idl
    $(IDLCC) $(IDLFLAGS) @^

EXTRA_CORBA_SOURCES = ${srcdir}/idlscratch/blahSK.cc

endif
```

This rule should invoke the IDL compiler to make it spit out the .cc/.hh files in *${srcdir}/idlscratch/* however, it does not seem to be invoking the compiler, instead I get:

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `idlscratch/blahSK.cc', needed by `blahSK.o'. Stop.
```

I find, however, if I manually invoke the IDL compiler and place the .hh/.cc files in the *${srcdir}/idlscratch* directory, that the compile completes successfully.

So it seems that make isn't recognizing the blahSK.cc file as needing to invoke the IDL compiler when it's in a sub directory.

**What is the proper way to create a rule that will cause the make system to properly invoke the IDL compiler when the output is a subdirectory?**

Comment: which CORBA IDL compiler?

Comment: It's not really relevant to how the invocation with make occurs, but I'm using Omni ORB 4.2.0.

Comment: The reason I ask is that TAO takes care of this for you automatically using the MPC tool.

Answer (score 2):

The relevant detail here is "and place the .hh/.cc files in the ${srcdir}/idlscratch directory". Do that and it'll work in make too.

The problem is that a rule like `%SK.cc: %.idl` requires make (by default) to find both the target and its prereqs in the same location and your source files and desired output files are not in the same location anymore.

You can get around this in a number of ways. The simplest is to use the `vpath` directive/feature of make to instruct it that there are additional source directories to search in when searching for prerequisites. Adding `vpath %.idl ${srcdir}` to the makefile might be enough to make this work.

Alternatively you can manually (well semi-manually) create the relationships between the individual input and output files and then use a `%SK.cc:` rule (note: no `%.idl` prereq on this line) to provide the recipe to build `%SK.cc` files (using the previously set up prerequisite lists).

Answer (score 1):

After some experimentation, I was able to create the following rule that works:

```
if MAKE_CORBA
IDLFLAGS = -bcxx -C${srcdir}/idlscratch/ -I$(IDLINCPATH)

$(shell mkdir -p ${srcdir}/idlscratch/

${srcdir}/idlscratch/%SK.cc: $(IDLPATH)/%.idl
    $(IDLCC) $(IDLFLAGS) $^

AM_CPPFLAGS += -I$(srcdir)/idlscratch/

EXTRA_CORBA_SOURCES = ${srcdir}/idlscratch/blahSK.cc

endif
```

With this rule, make checks if it needs to build *blahSK.cc* in *${srcdir}/idlscratch/* based on whether or not it has a matching .idl file in *$(IDLPATH).*

Building in a scratch dir like this has the added benefit that you can add a rule to make clean that will blow away the idlscratch dir and force a recompile of .idl->.cc on the next make. Otherwise, the compiler wouldn't try to remake the %SK.cc files unless it noticed a change in the corresponding .idl file.

Comment: This certainly works. I'm not sure why I didn't list this as an option in my answer as well. I suppose I assumed you wanted to keep the more general `%SK.cc` rule intact.